# Grunt - Minimize a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, task, minimize

I made a small project that has more than one directive for example:

```
[Folder_MyAppDirective]
    (myApp_Directive.js)
    (myApp_Controller.js)
    (myApp_Service.js)
    (myApp_View.html)
```

my problem is that i would like to get just one minifile with all the content,

```
myAppDirective.min.js
```

Is it posible do it with Grunt ?
I'm new with this tool, can somebody help me?

Thanks

Comment: There is a npm module for that you can use named **grunt-contrib-uglify**. I use it with basic compression and it does the job well. Here is details: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin like [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify), then you can set up separate minification tasks for each of your directives.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `yeoman/yo` and `generator-angular` for scaffolding? It has also nicely done concat and minification

but if you only want to concat those files into one then grunt-contrib-concat is your tool

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat